# How to save part of URL in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to save part of a URL in the save method for example :

I have this link from youtube:

www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMXHHuEGuO8

but i just want to save this part :  wMXHHuEGuO8

how can i do that in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is specific to Python 3, and doesn't use any Django-specific calls. You can use the [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) module to parse URLs into their parts:

```
import urllib.parse

url = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMXHHuEGuO8'

query_string =  urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query
print(query_string)
# v=wMXHHuEGuO8

query_dict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query_string)
print(query_dict)
# {'v': ['wMXHHuEGuO8']}

print(query_dict['v'])
# ['wMXHHuEGuO8']

print(query_dict['v'][0])
# wMXHHuEGuO8
```

Answer (score -2):

If it always is the same format like youtube.com/watch?v= you can split it like this:

```
your_url = www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMXHHuEGuO8
splited = your_url.split('watch?v=') 
# you will have a list of two elements, first one is
# www.youtube.com/ and the other one is wMXHHuEGuO8
```